# How can I ensure amortized O(n) concatenation from Data.Vector?

Tags: haskell, vector, amortized-analysis

I have an application where it is efficient to use Vectors for one part of the code. However, during the computation I need to keep track of some of the elements. I have heard that you can get O(n) amortized concatenation from Data.Vectors (by the usual array growing trick) but I think that I am not doing it right. So lets say we have the following setup:

```
import Data.Vector((++),Vector)
import Prelude hiding ((++))
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

data App = S (Vector Int)

add :: Vector Int -> State App ()
add v1 = modify (\S v2 -> S (v2 ++ v1))
```

Does `add` run in amortized O(n) time in this case? If not, how can I make `add` do that (do I need to store an `(forall s. MVector s Int)` in the State?). Is there a more efficient way of implementing `add`?

Comment: @hvr: No that is not what I want. I am pretty sure I am not doing it correctly in my question. However, I don't know the Data.Vector library that well and although the documentation `(++)` only states that it is *O(m+n)* worst case, it might still have *O(n)* amortized runtime.

Comment: So I hate it when people on StackOverflow answer questions with questions, but I'm about to do it :P - Why do you think you're doing it "wrong"? I assume you're using `State` for some reason unrelated to this question, so if you strip the `State`-related stuff away it's clear you're not doing anything crazy: <!-- language: lang-hs --> add :: Vector Int -> Vector Int -> Vector Int add v1 v2 = v1 ++ v2 - You noticed the docs say it runs in *O(n + m)* time; what led you to believe it should run faster?

Comment: Wrong might be too strong, I just wanted to say that I realize that add might end up being `O(n^2)* worst case. Also note that although something might run in *O(n+m)* worst case, it might run in *O(n)* amortized, the reason why I thought that could be achieved is that MVector can grow, (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable-Mutable.html#g:8), and the think I heard it somewhere. The reason I included State, and I know it is unclear, is that it is what I am doing in my application and it is not totally unrelated since I might store some other type.

Comment: Related followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7978130/283240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the vector library well either, so I have to stick to general principles mostly. Benchmark it, run a sequence of adds similar to what you expect in your application and see what performance you get. If it's 'good enough', great, stick with the simple code. If not, before storing a `(forall s. MVector s Int)` in the state (which you can't directly, tuples can't hold forall-types, so you'd need to wrap it), try improving the add-behaviour by converting to mutable vectors and perform the concatenation there before freezing to get an immutable vector again, roughly

```
add v1 = do
    S v2 <- get
    let v3 = runST $ do
                m1 <- unsafeThaw v2
                m2 <- unsafeGrow m1 (length v1)
                -- copy contents of v1 behind contents of v2
                unsafeFreeze m2
    put (S v3)
```

You may need to insert some strictness there. However, if unsafeGrow needs to copy, that will not guarantee amortized O(n) behaviour.

You can get amortized O(n) behaviour by

1. storing the number of used slots in the state too
2. if the new vector fits in the free space at the end, thaw, copy, freeze without growing
3. if it doesn't fit in the free space, grow by at least a factor of 2, that guarantees that each element is copied at most twice on average

Comment: The order of wich it is added was wrong in the question so I changed it. The first case In your question is what I am after...

Comment: Updated to match revised question.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think to get amoritized O(n), you don't need a grow factor of 2. I think it just has to be greater than 1 (but you need to check that you are growing at least by 1 element with small lists).

Comment: You're right of course, any factor q > 1 will do, with a bound of q/(q-1) on the number of copies. If memory is a concern, smaller factors may be preferable, I picked 2 because it's easy and keeps the number of copies low.